# Why isn't this simple JPA ManyToOne relationship working?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm using JPA with Java EE 5 (IBM RAD 7.5 and WebSphere 7).  I've simplified my problem to the following example ...

I have a Project and a User.  The tables look like this:

```
PROJECT
--
id
name
projectmanagerid // is a User

USER
--
id
username
```

My classes look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECT")
class Project
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(...)
  Long id;
  String name;
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="projectmanagerid");
  User projectManager;

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
class User
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(...)
  Long id;
  String username;
```

To retrieve my Project I do this:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select distinct p from Project p");
query.getResult...
```

Everything works except the `project.projectManager` is always `null`.

Shouldn't `FetchType.EAGER` cause the user to get populated?  What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Rob

Comment: is the projectmanagerid field populated as you expect (i.e. not null) in the database before you issue the query?

Comment: If it's null, then the foreign key is null. Whether the fetch type is eager or not doesn't change anything. If it was lazy, you would have a non-initialized proxy to the user, but not null.

Comment: Yes, the projectmanagerid field is populated in the database.  Any ideas?  Is there some configuration value missing in an XML file somewhere or something?  I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like I found the answer to my problem so I'll post it here.  Hopefully it might help others.

In IBM RAD 7.5, the JPA project properties has a setting called "Platform".  The default value is "RAD JPA Platform".  When I changed it "Generic" and now it works.

Note: I also changed `@JoinColum` to `@Column` as suggested by tomred, not sure if that did anything, tho.

Thanks all!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

In the case you should just be able to map this with the @Column annotation as join column is for instance where the reference is on the other side of the relationship

Project -> (has a) User then Project has @Column with name="projectmanagerid"

if on the other had user referenced project then you would have

User -> (has a) Project then Project has @JoinColumn with name="projectid"

Presently you are stating the the user table has a reference column called projectmanagerid which is not the case.

I hope this helps,
TomRed