# JOIN column returns null while using JPA on RAD 7.5

Tags: jpa, rad

I'm using JPA on RAD7.5. Entities i'm using are defined below. Everytime I'm accesisng Pgm joined Typ is returning as null.

```
@Entity
public class Typ implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="TYP_ID")
    private int TypId;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="TypId")
private Set<Pgm> pgmCollection;
}

@Entity
public class Pgm implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="TYP_ID")
    private Typ TypId;}
```

I referenced following link - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10702626/1483063   and tried 'generic' option as well, no gain though.
Tried query `Select F.* from PGM F` with 'Fetch JOIN' that didn't help either. 
Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data on the database, is the foreign key null?

Your @JoinColumn does not make sense,

insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false

How is this column inserted if you have insertable = false?

Comment: Both Pgm and Typ table have one record manually added in each.  Query <select * from pgm p, typ t where p.Typ_ID = t.Typ_ID> retruns single joined record on db2client. I'm removing removing following <insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false>.